# Disk [videos] does not have a configured driver

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a thumbnail using laravel and ffmpeg. But am getting this error.

Disk [videos] does not have a configured driver.

My code

```
public function index()
{
    FFMpeg::fromDisk('videos')
        ->open('steve_howe.mp4')
        ->getFrameFromSeconds(10)
        ->export()
        ->toDisk('thumnails')
        ->save('FrameAt10sec.png');
    // $videos =  Videos::where('user_email', Auth::user()->email)->get();
    //  return view('instructor.videos')->with('videost', $videos);
}
```

What could be the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open your config file `config/filesystems.php` and check the key `videos`,  make sure it contains `'driver' => 'local'` or any other driver that you are wanting to use.

Example

```php
'videos' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('videos'),
],
```

Answer (score 36):

i've tried on Laravel 6, it's shown : "InvalidArgumentException: Disk [public2] does not have a configured driver."

what I've tried on config/filesystem.php

```
    'public2' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/public',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

then tried :

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

still shown exception error.
May i know what I must todo ?
Thank you a lot

**SOLVED**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: `config:clear` is what I was missing also, thanks :D

Comment: `dump-autoload` did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when trying to use FFMpeg in a Laravel Job.

I solved it by just restarting the queue using

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this. Laravel 7.

```
return Storage::download('folder/file');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if the disk name contains a period/full-stop character, for example, `foo.bar`, which has to do with how the framework implements dot-notation in configuration directive names. Using `foo-bar` will resolve the problem.