# Retrieving path error while displaying image from the Database in Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, localhost

I'm kind of facing error in displaying image from database. It's showing a  path error like "doesn't have configured Driver

..
`Disk [uploads/] does not have a configured driver. (View: C:\xamppz\htdocs\webProject\resources\views\records.blade.php)`

Even the i configured the file in the filesystem, it's showing the error.
Help me to get rid this problem.

```
@foreach($blogs as $key => $blog)
<tr>
  <th scope="row"> {{ $blog->id}} </th> 
  <td> {{ $blog->first_name}} </td> 
  <td> {{ $blog->last_name}} </td> 
  <td> {{ $blog->email}} </td> 
  <td><img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="{{ Storage::disk('uploads/'.$blog->image) }}" alt="image" width="50"> </td> 
  <td> {{ $blog->description}} </td> 
  <td> {{ $blog->created_at}} </td> 
  <td> {{ $blog->updated_at}} </td> 
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disk \[videos\] does not have a configured driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59612172/disk-videos-does-not-have-a-configured-driver)

Comment: Could you add your config/filesystems.php file ?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use like that

```
<img class="img-responsive thumbnail" src="{{ url('uploads/'.$blog->image) }}" alt="image" width="50">
```

Comment: Thanks the error is gone. But i cant see the image that i uploaded.
Default image icon is there. How make view my actual image?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Laravel Documentation

> When using the local driver, all file operations are relative to the
>   `root` directory defined in your `filesystems` configuration file. By
>   default, this value is set to the `storage/app` directory.

So by default your code looks for image inside storage/app. You can configure your mappings in your `filesystems` configuration file as follow

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('uploads'),
],
```

Reference: 
[Laravel -> File Storage -> The Local Driver](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-local-driver)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for public url you have to define as public driver neither then local driver. But you should consider your system security.